# Get all keys with specific value in dictionary Python

Tags: python, dictionary

Is it possible to get all the keys matching a specific value from a Python dictionary?

For example, I have a dictionary with the following data:

```
dataset = [

        {'name': 'A', 'age': 37, 'gender': 'M'},
        {'name': 'B', 'age': 20, 'gender': 'F'},
        {'name': 'C', 'age': 17, 'gender': 'M'},
        {'name': 'D', 'age': 19, 'gender': 'F'},
        {'name': 'E', 'age': 30, 'gender': 'F'}
    ]
```

I would like to filter the dictionary and get all the keys where the Gender='F'.

I run the below line to filter the key 'Gender' for value 'F'.

```
res = next((sub for sub in dataset if sub['gender'] == 'F'), None)
print(res)
```

However, I get only 1 key as output.

Output:
`{'name': 'B', 'age': 27, 'gender': 'F'}`

Want this as output:

```
{'name': 'B', 'age': 20, 'gender': 'F'}
{'name': 'D', 'age': 19, 'gender': 'F'}
{'name': 'E', 'age': 30, 'gender': 'F'}
```

Comment: Yes, it is possible. What makes you think it might not be? This is not exactly the halting problem.

Comment: What is it that you think `next` does?

Comment: Just a hint: `(sub for sub in dataset if sub['gender'] == 'F')` is something you can iterate over. The same with square brackets is a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use conditional list comprehension like this:

`[i for i in dataset if i['gender'] == 'F']`

which should give:

`[{'name': 'B', 'age': 20, 'gender': 'F'}, {'name': 'D', 'age': 19, 'gender': 'F'}, {'name': 'E', 'age': 30, 'gender': 'F'}]`

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why you have used the next function, but simple list comprehension will do:

`res = [sub for sub in dataset if sub['gender'] == 'F']`

Answer (score 0):

You can also try the following code:

```
dataset = [{'name': 'A', 'age': 37, 'gender': 'M'}, {'name': 'B', 'age': 20, 'gender': 'F'}, {'name': 'C', 'age': 17, 'gender': 'M'}, {'name': 'D', 'age': 19, 'gender': 'F'},{'name': 'E', 'age': 30, 'gender': 'F'} ]
for i in dataset:
    if i['gender']=='F':
        print(i)
```